# Is it possible to iterate through only open/displayed Outlook emails using Python?

Tags: python, email, outlook

I'm trying to get information into python from an email in Outlook. I'm a beginner with python -- I've done a lot with win32api and selenium, but I haven't written any scripts to work with Outlook at all yet. That being said, I originally figured this would be pretty easy and now it seems like it may not be possible.

Everything I can find about python/Outlook is about looping through the entire inbox or a designated folder (basically handling a batch of emails stored somewhere). I don't want to do that though because the email's sender, subject, body content, folder location, etc. are all variable. I just want to loop through the emails that are currently open. Ideally I will double click on an email to open it from my inbox, run the code, and have the code reference that open email.

It's very easy for me to do this successfully in VBA and I use it all the time. I iterate through all open Outlook windows until a specific phrase (unique to the email I want) is found.

VBA:

```vb
For i = 1 To outlookApp.Inspectors.Count
    Set eMail = outlookApp.Inspectors.Item(i).CurrentItem
    'work with eMail
```

Python:

[equivalent if possible]

If it's not possible to do this using python, is there some other way that I can specify an individual email from my inbox for the code to reference? At the end of the day, I just need to pull some text out of it. The hard part is telling python which email has the text.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Did you try to debug the code? Where and when do you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what programming language is used. Python can be used for automating Outlook as well as other languages.

However, be aware that Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office?wa=wsignin1.0%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0) article.

A possible workaround is to use a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI or any other third-party wrapper around that API such as Redemption. EWS is also a possible way to go. Read more about that in the [Start using web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange) article.